# fragment error android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to do a tabbed activity with 3 fragments android studio but my code crash when I try to go to another tab.

The problem I believe in this part but I'm not able to solve it

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ==1)
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_settings, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
        else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)== 2)
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
        else
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_courses, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Please post stack trace

Comment: You can get help from https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/